# When and where should we use these keras LSTM models

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I know how a RNN, LSTM, neural nets,activation function works but from various available LSTM models I dont know what should I use for which data and when. I created these 5 models as a sample of different varites of LSTM models I have seen but I dont know which optimal sequence dataset should use. I have most of my confussion in the second/third lines of these models.  Are model1 and model4 are same? Why is `model1.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(max_len, 1), return_sequences=False))` different from `model4.add(Embedding(X_train.shape[1], 128, input_length=max_len))` . I would much appreciate If some one can explain these five models in simple english.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

#model1
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(max_len, 1), return_sequences=False))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print model1.summary()

#model2
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(10, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print model2.summary()


#model3
model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(X_train.shape[1]), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
model3.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=False))
model3.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model3.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print model3.summary()


#model4
model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(Embedding(X_train.shape[1], 128, input_length=max_len))
model4.add(LSTM(10))
model4.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model4.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print model4.summary()

#model5
model5 = Sequential()
model5.add(Embedding(X_train.shape[1], 128, input_length=max_len))
model5.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10)))
model5.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model5.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print model5.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

1. First network is the best one for classification. It's simply analysing the whole sequence - and once all input steps are fed to a model - it's able to perform a decision. There are other variants of this architecture (using e.g. `GlobalAveragePooling1D` or max one) which are pretty similiar from a conceptual point of view.
2. Second network - from a design point of view is quite similar to a first architecture. What differs them is the fact that in a first approach two consequent `fit` and `predict` calls are totally independent, whereas here - the starting state for second call is the same to the last one in a first. This enables a lot of cool scenarios like e.g. varying length sequences analysis or e.g. decision making processes thanks to the fact that you could effecitively stop inference / training process - affect network or input and come back to it with actualized state.
3. Is the best one when you don't want to use recurrent network at all stages of your computations. Especially - when your network is big - introducing a recurrent layers is quite costly from a parameter number point of view (introducing a recurrent connection usually increases the number of parameter by a factor of at least 2). So you could apply a static network as a preprocessing stage - and then you feed results to a recurrent part. This makes training easier.
4. Model is a special case of case 3. Here - you have a sequence of tokens which are coded by a one-hot encoding and then transformed using `Embedding`. This makes the process less memory consuming.
5. Bidrectional network provides you an advantage of knowing at each step not only a sequence previous history - but also further steps. This is at computational cost and also you are losing the possibilty of a sequential data feed - as you need to have a full sequence when analysis is performed.